# Solr on Tomcat (Ubuntu OS) installation

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, security, solr

I have to install Solr on my Ubuntu Server.
However, Solr wont work without Tomcat or another container, and also Java.

I have successfully installed tomcat6 and java.

BUT, in a tomcat6 guide online, it says I should configure iptables to allow connections via port 8080, which I have done. Then the guide says I can test the tomcat6 by going to:

```
  http://my_ip_adress:8080
```

But this makes the browser just load and wait somehow for a response, and finally display "website not available".

I have NO clue how to install Solr with Tomcat.
Does anybody know how?

How do I know Tomcat6 works?

BTW: When I do this: `/etc/init.d/tomcat6` start then it says OK.

If you need something let me know, I really need help with this one.

Thanks

UPDATE:

When executing this: `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 status` it respons is `Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 28641`

Comment: Check that it's actually lisening on port 8080, lsof -i :8080 . If yes, check $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out to see if there are any errors. If no errors, check locally using a commandline client like elinks or similar, i.e. elinks http://127.0.0.1:8080 . See Tomcat default page? Yes, you still have some firewall rule or something else blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Solr will run without Tomcat. If you check out the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html) on the website their demo instance runs on Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

We got solr with tomcat to work.  The docs say use port 8080, but in fact the app server is listening on a different port.  I think it was 8088.  The docs actually give you both ports.  It was confusing to me.  You can use the following command to tell you what port you need:
    % sudo lsof | grep tomcat | grep TCP

You'll see which ports tomcat is listening on.  If it doesn't help, the tomcat output is very chatty; printing to stderr when you start solr.  Maybe you could paste the last 20-30 lines form that output here?